# QSqlQuery, bind a null when QLineEdit is empty

Tags: c++, sql, qt

I'm working on a database application and need to write a `NULL` value to the database when a `QLinEdit` is empty (as opposed to a white space which seems to be the default behavior).

The following code is close to working, though it always writes `NULL`'s to the database, even when a `QLinEdit` is contains a text string. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Example Code:

```
QSqlQuery qry;

qry.prepare("insert into [DB] (BUSN_MNGR) values (:BUSN_MNGR)");

QString BUSN_MNGR;

BUSN_MNGR=ui->txt_BUSN_MNGR->text();

qry.bindValue("BUSN_MNGR", BUSN_MNGR.isEmpty() ? QVariant(QVariant::String): BUSN_MNGR);  // bind null if the string is empty

qry.exec .... etc.
```

For some reason only `NULLs` are passed to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the colon at the beginning of the placeholder name, as per the documentation:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#bindValue

So it would look more like this:

```
qry.bindValue(":BUSN_MNGR", /* ... */);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Forest Darling!

If anyone else is interested, I solved my problem with the following tweaks to the code:

```
 qry.bindValue(":BUSN_MNGR", ui->txt_BUSN_MNGR->text().trimmed().isEmpty() ? QVariant(QVariant::String): ui->txt_BUSN_MNGR->text());
```